# Корутины в использовании базы данных Kotlin

Tags: sqlite, kotlin, concurrency

Я новичок в kotlin. Не совсем понимаю, как можно организовать concurrency в работе с базами данных SQLite, в частности корутины. Может ли кто-то, пожалуйста, обьяснить как это сделать?

Comment: Любой запрос в БД требует времени и ресурсов на исполнение. Поэтому его лучше делать асинхронно. Все точно так же как и с сетевыми запросами.

Comment: Не очень понятно что Вы имеете ввиду под concurency в SQLite. Если Вам важно, чтобы данные были максимально актуальны, то делайте свои Query вместе с аннотацией Transaction